# Getting specific column data from database in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a search function that returns product data in a `DataGridView` (data is coming from local database), it does work but I need to have control over returned data in my grid view.

#### Current behavior

It returns all columns of database row in `DataGridView`

#### What I want

1. Returning only 2 or 3 columns of searched item instead of all columns
2. Create new list of searched items so I can edit those returned data

#### Logic

1. Search for product
2. Get product *name and price from database*, *add custom quantity field* make new list and add this item to show in `DataGridView`
3. Be able to change quantity field in `DataGridView`

#### Code

Here is my search code that returns all columns of product table

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where Id=@Id or Name like @Name", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", searchBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", string.Format("%{0}%", searchBox.Text));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);


            // Following line will show all columns of founded product and replace it with next search result
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            selectedItems.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

> PS: Code above finds products based on `id` or `name` entered in search field and return all columns of product row.

#### Idea:

I think I can be able to create my list after finding product but the issue I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to get those specific columns from my `dt` (table row),

Here is what I've tried and failed (commented)

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDatabaseWalkthrough.Properties.Settings.SampleDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        cn.Open();
    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Products"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Products where Id=@Id or Name like @Name", cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", searchBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", string.Format("%{0}%", searchBox.Text));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            //selectedItems.DataSource = dt; //<-- changed with lines below


            List<string> items = new List<string>();
            items.Add(dt); // <-- here is the issue (it expect to get string of my table row let say: Price column, but I don't know how to get Price column value from dt)
            selectedItems.DataSource = items;
        }
    }
}
```

> PS: code above is just idea and obviously I am not sure if it is best way to do it or not that's why I'm asking here :)

**Any suggestions?**

#### Update

I've created new class and added my data to that class as following

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Price { get; set; }
  public string Qty { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my query I added

```
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  Item item = new Item();
  item.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Id"]);
  item.Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
  item.Price = dt.Rows[i]["SellPrice"].ToString();
  item.Qty = dt.Rows[i]["Qty"].ToString();
  itemList.Add(item);
}
selectedItems.DataSource = itemList;
```

Now it does return data in my `selectedItems` but when I search for next product instead of adding it to the list it replace it with first product.

Comment: Are you trying to gain performance by reducing the columns or do you just want a dynamic piece of code that only reads certain columns, or are you trying to morph the result and do calculations on what was received?

Comment: Can you add information about which columns would need to be selected? is it a list of string passed to the method so you know which columns you need?

Comment: @Neil Ok got confused :D here is what I want, `1` search in products table by id or name `2` get values of name, price columns from founded row `3` add those data to new list so I can show it in my grid view

Comment: If you can give more detail on `selectedItems` I could improve my answer for you

Comment: @mafortis, is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding based on the comments, you are looking for some Linq code.
You only need to convert your result to a list that you could use.

Here is some code that might help you achieve this.

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> new {
                                Id = x["Id"],
                                Name = x["Name"],
                                Quantity = {Your Logic here}
                         });

selectedItems.DataSource = result;
```

You can then assign `result` to your datasource. You did not specify what your datasource is assigned to (`selectedItems`) so I do not know what type it is. but this should theoretically work. Just remove `Quantity = {Your Logic here}` from the code and see if it display's after which you could then just add it back and populate what you want Quantity to be

**UPDATE**

Because `selectedItems` is a DataGridView it requires a `DataTable` object to display the data. In which case you can not use an anonymous list as I created you would need something like this.

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("Id");
dtResult.Columns.Add("Name");
dtResult.Columns.Add("Quantity");

var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> dtResult.Rows.Add(x["Id"],
                                               x["Name"],
                                               {Your Logic for Quantity here}
                         ));

selectedItems.DataSource = result;
```

If you want to test this solution you can create a console application in c# and do something like where you can see the datasource is correct.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to test your code now, `selectedItems` is name of my `DataGridView` tool

Comment: No it does not show any data in my grid view

Comment: I think there is closing code issue in your update code

Comment: It was the `}` I have removed it

Comment: Here is screenshot of the result https://ibb.co/4d66zx2

Comment: Add a breakpoint on your assignment and see if the datasource is empty. if so Add a breakpoint higher. that code should be working. is your source not empty?

Comment: Sorry to act like idiot :D but it's my very first C# attempt not sure how to do breakpoint things, and no my data is not empty If I use my basic code (selectedItems.DataSource = dt;) it does show the results in `selectedItems`

Comment: Ok I have made a small change. Please try that by declaring the result then using it

Comment: When I do `Console.WriteLine($"{result}");` it says `System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection1[System.Data.DataRow]` in console.

Comment: let me dupplicate this project so I can give you a better answer. this was just meant to be a quick fix. Give me 5 min. I will post a new answer

Comment: I see. That seems like a different issue that needs more detail. Nice solution to your problem creating the object.

Comment: Thanks but it is still same issue due, if you see my comment in `Code` part `// Following line will show all columns of founded product and replace it with next search result`  I've mentioned that one of the issue is new search is replacing with old ones. How can I keep my `itemList` items when I search for new product and not reset it?

Comment: But it will replace because you are assigning the new result to the datasource. you will need to store your result in another variable like a global variable and add to that result if you want your search result to add to the main search page. (Not really sure what you need to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

According to your sql query you are selecting all columns of the table.

To get the specific columns please change your sql query as such:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Products.id, Products.name from Products where Id=@Id or Name like @Name", cn);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, yes that does get my specific columns for it does not solve my logic #2 and #3 (adding quantity field, edit that quantity) any suggestion on that? `PS` it also wont solve next search replacement issue (commented in Code part)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following code to show specific column data from database in winform datagirdview.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "str";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Product where Id=@Id or Name like @Name";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", string.Format("%{0}%", textBox1.Text));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(table);
            var dt = from t in table.AsEnumerable()
                           select new
                           {
                               //Name=t.Field<string>("Name"),     //The same way to show other columns data 
                               Price = t.Field<string>("Price")
    
                           };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.ToList();


        }
```

Result:

[image]

Database:

[image]